# Fix the value of the vertical space before/after \Large

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, line-spacing

Is there any way to fix the value of the vertical space before and after `{\Large ...}` to be 1.0em? Sometimes I use `{\Large ...}` just after or before a theorem and the theorem spacing requirements seem to have priority. The same thing possibly happens if I use `{\Large ...}` after or before a math equation. E.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{parskip, enumerate, xcolor, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mydef}
  {1.0em}   % ABOVESPACE
  {1.0em}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont} % BODYFONT
  {0pt} % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries}   % HEADFONT
  {.}   % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}  % HEADSPACE
  {}    % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{mydef}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\Largebf}[1]{\textbf{{\Large #1 }}}

\begin{document}
    \Largebf{Introduction}

    \begin{thm}
        Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval (bounded or not) and let $(f_n) : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of $C^1$ functions. Suppose
        \begin{enumerate}[i)]
          \item $f_n \to f$ simply on $I$;
          \item $f_n' \to g$ uniformly on $I$.
        \end{enumerate}
        Then $f$ is differentiable on $I$ and $f' = g$. Put differently, under these hypotheses,
        \[
            (\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n)' = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n'.
        \]
    \end{thm}

    \Largebf{Wonderful result}

    \textcolor{red}{Write this.}

    \Largebf{Not-so-wonderful result}

    The following theorem should not be surprising :
    \[
        1 \neq 19.
    \]

    \Largebf{Conclusion}

    This would be the conclusion!
\end{document}
```

So my **question** is: How to fix the value of the vertical space before and after `{\Large ...}` (or `\Largebf{...}` as in the code above) to be, say, 1.0em, no matter what (I want to give this condition the first priority).

Comment: As an aside, your use of `\Large` should be `{\Large ...}` and not `\Large{...}`.

Comment: @Werner Indeed. I edited my question to take this into account.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use `\newcommand{\Largebf}[1]{\section*{#1}}` rather than your current definition.

Comment: @Werner I prefer using `\subsection*` and it's perfect like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use some sectioning command rather than your font-change macro. Perhaps

```
\newcommand{\Largebf}{\subsection*}
```

or the like.

Why doesn't `\textbf{\Large ...}` provide the desired spacing? That's because font switching macros doesn't take the `\baselineskip` into account unless a `\par`agraph is set (or a proper `\strut` is inserted). The easiest way around this is the above suggestion, which covers a lot of ground in terms of document structure.

Comment: In that case I don't even need to define a new command.